# Pycharm Requirement already satisfied but not add lib

Tags: python, pycharm

When I was running `pip install numpy` it says `Requirement already satisfied`.
However, `env\lib\site-packages`  doesn't seem to have lib `numpy`. As a result, when I ran project I was getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`. How should I resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Check if you have select the same environment for 'Run/Debug Configuration"

Comment: Could you please try to re-install `numpy`? Since I have `numpy` directory along with `numpy-<version>.dist-info`